# How to strip/remove all blank spaces at the beginning/end of a search string

Tags: php, search, regex

I use hack of [Chris_O](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/251/chris-o) for highlighting the search terms. When a user enters the search keywords without any blank space in the beginning or at end of the search string it retrieves and highlights the search terms in the corresponding records nicely.

But if the user enters the search string with blank_space in the beginning or at the end, it retrieves and highlights the the search terms but all non-english portions of the post content appears weird (like ���� or ????). Although the english content appears fine but with tags (e..g, `<p style="text-align: center;">test site</p>` etc.)

Is it possible in the hack to strip/remove all blank spaces at the beginning/end of a search string? thanks a lot.

I use version 3.1.4 with the default twentyten theme.

Here is the Hack:

Step 1:

Add these 2 functions to your functions.php

```
function search_content_highlight()
{
    $content = get_the_content();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $content = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">'placeholder4'</strong>', $content);
    echo '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
}

function search_title_highlight()
{
    $title = get_the_title();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $title = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">'placeholder4'</strong>', $title);
    echo $title;
}
```

Step 2:

In my theme's loop.php file  I call `<?php search_title_highlight(); ?>` instead of `<?php the_title(); ?>` and use `<?php search_content_highlight(); ?>` instead of `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Step 3: In my css add the search-highlight class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree w/ chip, you need trim()

i'd try replacing:

`$keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));`

with

`$keys = implode('|', explode(' ', trim(get_search_query())));`

Comment: How do you trim this white space in a normal search setup where there is no `get_search_query()` to modify?

Answer (score 1):

[Use the PHP function `trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: Bennett, thanks for the reply. Chip please tell me how to use it. Thanks a lot.